# Qt Checkbox not visible

Tags: c++, qt

I have two applications:

1. Both displays QCheckBox text correctly
2. Both use the same css stylesheet
3. All the settings in the widget editor seem to the the same

The check box square is not visible for one application while it is for the other.

Editor view of the QCheckbox.

[image: editor]

The application that is working

[image: working]

The application that is not working.

[image: not working]

In response to  Pavel Strakhov:

```
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
      <item>
       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="c">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Display</string>
        </property>
        <property name="checked">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="logToFile">
        <property name="text">
         <string>To File</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is cause because there is a global image file used, so the check box will not be visible. I resolve the issue by making a new checkbox image and applied it to all checkboxes in the css.